# StaleObjectException with UiAutomator 2.0

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am moving from uiautomator to uiautomator 2.0. I am having some troubles with an old UiWatcher.

I am using this function to set the battery level and check that the application prints the correct level. Here is the code.

```
private void setLevel(int oldL, int newL) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
    UiWatcher okBatteryDialogWatcher = new UiWatcher() {
        @Override
        public boolean checkForCondition() {
            UiObject okCancelDialog = new UiObject(new UiSelector().textContains("Connect charger"));
            if(okCancelDialog != null){
                UiObject okButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(Button.class.getName()).text("OK"));
                okButton.click();
                return device.waitForWindowUpdate("",10000);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    getUiDevice().registerWatcher("Battery dialog watcher", okBatteryDialogWatcher);
    getUiDevice().runWatchers();

    UiObject batteryLevel = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text(oldL + " %"));
    assertTrue("Battery level not found", batteryLevel.exists());

    BatteryDelegate.getInstance().setBatteryLevel(newL);

    batteryLevel = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text(newL + " %"));
    assertTrue("Battery level not found", batteryLevel.exists());
}
```

This code works fine. Now I want to change it in order to use new features provided by uiautomator 2.0.

```
private void setLevel(int oldL, int newL) {
    UiWatcher okBatteryDialogWatcher = new UiWatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean checkForCondition() {
                UiObject2 okCancelDialog = device.findObject(By.textContains("Connect charger"));
                if(okCancelDialog != null){
                    UiObject2 okButton = device.findObject(By.clazz(Button.class.getName()).text("OK"));
                    okButton.click();
                    return device.waitForWindowUpdate("",10000);
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

    device.registerWatcher("Battery dialog watcher", okBatteryDialogWatcher);
    device.runWatchers();

    UiObject2 batteryLevel = device.findObject(By.text(oldL + " %"));
    assertTrue("Battery level not found", batteryLevel != null);

    BatteryDelegate.getInstance().setBatteryLevel(newL);

    Boolean b = batteryLevel.wait(Until.textEquals(newL + " %"), 10000);
    assertTrue("Battery level not found", b != null && b.booleanValue());
}
```

When I use this code to set the battery level to 5% (a dialog 'Battery low' appears), a StaleObjectException is raised on the line `Boolean b = batteryLevel.wait(Until.textEquals(newL + " %"), 10000);`

Here is the exception

```
android.support.test.uiautomator.StaleObjectException
at android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject2.getAccessibilityNodeInfo(UiObject2.java:622)
at android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject2.getText(UiObject2.java:287)
at android.support.test.uiautomator.Until$15.apply(Until.java:277)
at android.support.test.uiautomator.Until$15.apply(Until.java:274)
at android.support.test.uiautomator.WaitMixin.wait(WaitMixin.java:49)
at android.support.test.uiautomator.WaitMixin.wait(WaitMixin.java:34)
at android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject2.wait(UiObject2.java:144)
at com.mycompany.myproject.demo.sensor.BatteryTestCase.setLevel(BatteryTestCase.java:89)
at com.mycompany.myproject.demo.sensor.BatteryTestCase.testUS2(BatteryTestCase.java:44)
...
```

I understand that the execption is due to the dialog but my watcher becomes useless. I can handle this exception with some trick like

```
....
Boolean b = null;
try {
    b = batteryLevel.wait(Until.textEquals(newL + " %"), 10000);
} catch (StaleObjectException e) {
    UiObject2 okCancelDialog = device.findObject(By.textContains("Connect charger"));
    if(okCancelDialog != null){
        UiObject2 okButton = device.findObject(By.clazz(Button.class.getName()).text("OK"));
        okButton.click();
        device.waitForWindowUpdate("",10000);
        b = batteryLevel.wait(Until.textEquals(newL + " %"), 10000);
    }
}
assertTrue("Battery level not found", b != null && b.booleanValue());
...
```

But this is absolutely not beautiful. Does someone

- encounter the same problem ?
- have a nice working solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue should be fixed in UiAutomator 2.1.0. Watchers were only being triggered on the initial call to `UiDevice.findObject(..)` and would not prevent StaleObjectExceptions.

In the latest release, watchers will also be triggered in cases where you would get a StaleObjectException. If you grab the latest Android Support Repository (rev. 13) and update your build file to depend on uiautomator-v18:2.1+ the problem will go away.

Comment: @ThomasThiebaud I am facing same issue.
can you tell me how have you upgraded to "uiautomator-v18:2.1.1"

Comment: @Ashish Have you figured it